# Concatenating FOR loop output

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am very new to Python (first week of active use). I have some bash scripting experience but have decided to learn Python.

I have a variable of multiple strings which I am using to build a URL in FOR loop. The output of URL is JSON and I would like to concatenate complete output into one file.

I will put random URL for privacy reasons.

The code looks like this:

**==================**

```
numbers = ['24246', '83367', '37643', '24245', '24241', '77968', '63157', '76004', '71665']

for id in numbers:
        restAPI = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, '/test/' + id + '&test2'))

result = restAPI.json
```

**==================**

the problem is that if I do **print(result)** I will get only output of last iteration, i.e. www.google.com/test/71665&test2

Creating a list by adding **text = []**  worked (content was concatenated) but I would like to keep the original format.

```
text = []

for id in numbers:

        restAPI = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, '/test/' + id + '&test2'))
```

Does anyone have idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `for` loop ends, the variable assigned inside the for loop only keeps the last value. I.e. Every time your code `for` loops through, the `restAPI` variable gets reset each time.

If you wanted to keep each URL, you could  `append` to a list outside the scope of the for loop every time, i.e.

```
restAPI = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, ...
url_list.append(restApi.json)
```

Or if you just wanted to print...

```
for id in numbers:
    restAPI = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, ...
    print(restAPI.json)
```

If you added them to a list, you could perform seperate functions with the new list of URLs.

If you think there might be duplicates, feel free to use a `set()` instead (which automatically removes the dupes inside the iterable as new values are added). You can use `set_name.add(restAPI.json)`

To be better, you could implement a `dict` and assign the `id` as the key and the json object as the value. So you could:

```
dict_obj = dict()

for id in numbers:
    restAPI = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, ...
    dict_obj[id] = restAPI.json
```

That way you can query the dictionary later in the script.

Note that if you're querying many URLs, storing the JSON's in memory might be intensive depending on your hardware.